# CMake MacOS app built in Big Sur won't run on Catalina

Tags: c++, macos, cmake

I've a project that I compiled in Big Sur (v 11.0) but it won't run in macOS Catalina (v 10.15). My CMakeLists.txt file contains

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(PROJECTNAME)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(LIBPROC_SRC "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/libproc.h")
set(CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET "10.15" CACHE STRING "Minimum OS X deployment version")
```

I have a bash script that sets many of the plist variables, including

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :LSMinimumSystemVersion 10.15.5" ~/Desktop/projectname/App/projectname.app/Contents/Info.plist
```

Shouldn't this be able to run in Catalina? I figure between setting the deployment target and the LSMinimumSystemVersion, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that the line

```
set(CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET "10.15" CACHE STRING "Minimum OS X deployment version")
```

should be before `project(PROJECTNAME)`

[See here for more info.](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET.html)